# How to make a smooth effect hover background-color?

Tags: html, css

I have a block with a picture in the background when hovering over it should smoothly change the background to color. Transition not work. The icon and text should remain as is.

```css
     .download-content {
        background-image: url("https://i.stack.imgur.com/M8HBU.jpg");
        background-color: #f60;
        background-position: center;
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        padding: 45px;
    }
     .download-content:hover {
        background-image: none;
        background-color: #f60;
        cursor:pointer
    }
```

```html
    <link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/5.0.0-alpha1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

    <div class="download-content">
      <div class="row justify-content-center">
        <div class="col-lg-8">
        <p>Lorem</p>
        <p><img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/CwiZM.png" width="60" height="60"></p>

        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Sorry, but you got closed before I had a chance to post my answer (yep, forgot to check for duplicates). Here's the [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/sjz56dw0/) instead...

Comment: My question was closed by moderators and answer link pointers. But they didn't help me.

Comment: Yeah, it happens. But did my Fiddle help?

Comment: In bootstrap 5.0.0-alpha1 the area covers the text and logo :(

Comment: 1) in your snippet you use 4.5.0 and 2) your issue is CSS related, not bootstrap related.

Comment: Sorry. Yes, I'm using 4.5.0 in the question, but when I migrate your code to my 5.0 project I got an overlap problem. Is it fixable?

Comment: Sorry, can't help you, not a bootstrap user and I am flying totally blind as I have only the code above and my Fiddle (which works).

Comment: I figured it out, thanks.